# Randomise next word with no duplicate in Hangman game using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have made a Hangman game using JavaScript. It works just fine, but I've found that every time I click on 'New Word' to start a new game, it's completely random (which is good), but it doesn't take into account whether or not the new word has already occurred/been played. So you get a lot of duplicates from previous words.

I have made about 50 words/answers that can appear. I just want it so that every time I click on 'New Word', it generates a new word (from my choices) at random, and doesn't ever duplicate the same word again, unless all other options/words have been played already.

For some reason this text box isn't putting all my code into a block, so to make things easier to read, this is a link to my code in Github. I've attached all files but I'm pretty sure you only need to look at my JavaScript code:

HTML:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kaw31/hangman/master/hangman.html

CSS: (I've commented out a bit of code from a previous version so just ignore that);

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kaw31/hangman/master/css/style.css

JavaScript:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kaw31/hangman/master/js/script.js

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: So you want the words that have already been used to be stored somewhere (are the words to be kept between page refreshes)? What have you tried? What kind of solution are you looking for (storing it serverside / clientside)?

Comment: Not sure if I need them to be stored anywhere. The words don't need to be kept between page refreshes. If you look at my JavaScript code, at the bottom there is a reset section. I think I just need to add a couple of lines saying something like if "X" word has been used, then don't use it again.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of logic errors in your code:

- The list of your categories is set every time you run `play` function - and for every game it's the same (that's why it's possible to retrieve a word that was retrieved in previous games), while it should be set once for given browser refresh. Therefore you should move `categories` to the top (`var categories = [list of your categories]`) so that it's persistent.
- You're not removing the chosen word after it has been retrieved from the list of your words - that's why it'll still be available to be retrieved again even with above fix. To do so, you first should get the index of category and word and simply remove it:

---

```
var category_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * categories.length);
var word_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * categories[category_index].length;

categories[category_index] = categories[category_index].splice(word_index, 1);
```

Of course at that point, you'll also have to remove hints and cater for the situation when list of words is empty (both - for each category, and empty at all)

Personally, I'd change how your words are stored, instead of using multiple arrays, use object as such:

```
var categories = [{
    title: "Sport Teams",
    words: [{
        word: "ARSENAL",
        hint: "Thierry Henry",
        }, ...
    ]}, ...
]
```

so, when retrieving a word, you're retrieving all information regarding it - at that point the list of words becomes more manageable and manipulation becomes a bit easier.

Comment: Ok. If I move categories and hints then won't that affect my play function and hint.onclick function? And if I change how my words are stored to what you've done, won't that affect the rest of my code. Is there any chance you could show me exactly how you'd change my entire code to how you'd store it for it to still work? I know it's a lot to ask (and no worries if you can't), but I'm a newbie to JavaScript and am scared that if I change one part of my code which then stops the rest from working entirely, I probably won't know how to fix it.

Comment: No - you're not specifying anywhere that you're working on local or global scope, so that part should still work. Yes, if you'll change it to what I'm proposing, you'll need the rest of code to be changed accordingly, but it makes dealing with other issues I've raised more easily. I'm sorry, but I cannot do that - I can try with questions/issues you might have, but I won't do the work for you :)